# How do I model the probability of a win in a particular matchup, given historical win/loss data for the players

Tags: probability, games

Let's say I have two numbers:

- the historical probability player A wins when playing a particular game (found by counting the number of times A has won, and dividing by the total number of times she has played), $P(win_A|A_{vs}anyone)$
- the historical probability player B loses when playing the same game (found by counting the number of times B has lost, and dividing by the total number of times she has played), $P(lose_B|anyone_{vs}B)$

Let's assume it's a game with no ties, i.e. win and lose are the only outcomes.

How do I use these two numbers to calculate the probability of A winning when she plays B, $P(win_A|A_{vs}B)$?

I've cast this question as a sports question. For example, you could imagine $P(win_A|A_{vs}anyone)$ being the historical batting average of hitter, and $P(lose_B|anyone_{vs}B)$ being the fraction of opponents a pitcher has faced who made a hit. Or these probabilities could by the historical probability of striker A scoring a penalty in football/soccer, and the probability of goalkeeper B conceding a penalty.

But it's a description of so many situations, and it seems so generic a problem that I assume I am missing something totally obvious! It *feels* somehow Bayesian to me, but I got in a mess trying to cast it in those terms.

**Bonus points**: how do you estimate $P(win_A|A_{vs}B)$ if $P(win_A|A_{vs}anyone)$ is expressed as a *distribution*, the probability of A winning *as a function of* the historical probability of their opponent losing, and $P(lose_B|anyone_{vs}B)$ is also a distribution as a function on the historical probability of their opponent winning.

**Notation**: feel free to adopt different notation if you find mine confusing, or there are better conventions!

Comment: One approach to this sort of problem would be models of the [Bradley-Terry (-Luce)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_comparison) type.

Comment: Yes, that looks along the right lines! Further thoughts very welcome though.